# How to match on corresponding data from two dataframes?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes. 
`dataframe_a`:

```
    data    | location_zone | test_hour |     analysis_date
------------+---------------+-----------+------------------------
  10        | america       |        12 | 2000-1-1
  11        | america       |        13 | 2000-1-2
  21        | china         |        14 | 2000-1-3
```

and `dataframe_b`:

```
    data    | location_zone | test_hour |     analysis_date
------------+---------------+-----------+------------------------
  1         | china         |        14 | 2000-1-3
  2         | america       |        13 | 2000-1-2
  3         | america       |        12 | 2000-1-1
```

And I need to combine these dataframes on corresponding `location_zone`, `test_hour`, and `analysis_date`, and add the `data` columns. The final result should be:

```
    data    | location_zone | test_hour |     analysis_date
------------+---------------+-----------+------------------------
  13        | america       |        12 | 2000-1-1
  13        | america       |        13 | 2000-1-2
  22        | china         |        14 | 2000-1-3
```

Comment: please check my answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df = pd.concat([dataframe_a, dataframe_b]).groupby(['location_zone','test_hour','analysis_date'], as_index=False)['data'].sum()
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  location_zone  test_hour analysis_date  data
0       america         12      2000-1-1    13
1       america         13      2000-1-2    13
2         china         14      2000-1-3    22
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both `df` have the same columns names, you may rename one `data` column to different name and let `merge` handle the rest. Next, call `eval` and slicing on original columns

```
df_final = (df_a.merge(df_b.rename(columns={'data': 'data_b'}))
                .eval('data=data + data_b')[df_a.columns])

Out[20]:
   data location_zone  test_hour analysis_date
0    13       america         12      2000-1-1
1    13       america         13      2000-1-2
2    22         china         14      2000-1-3
```